# Deploy compact framework without restart

Tags: .net, compact-framework

When you use visual studio to deploy to a windows mobile device it automatically picks the correct cab file and installs the compact framework onto that device. All without requiring a restart.

If you pick the same cab file and install it using active sync once the install is completed you are required to restart the device.

Why? And how can you so a silent install like visual studio does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you aren't required to restart it.  That's just a bug in the CAB.  [You can safely ignore it](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/d27c3c96-915b-4af2-be43-57747c6b93c8/) (though it is irritating).

Edit: You can suppress the message by passing in the [/noui or /silent switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158700.aspx) (depending on your target) to wceload.

Comment: Its good to know I can ignore it, However visual studio can make it not happen at all. I want to know how to do that.

Comment: I just updated my answer.  Studio does it by passing in the /noui switch.  This prevents the "already installed" message as well.

Comment: currently I use CEAPPMGR.exe from the pc to do the deployment. If I still want to trigger the install from the PC would I need to use the RAPI to call wceload? or is their a way to do it thru CEAPPMGR

Comment: Unfortunately CEAppMgr doesn't have any facility to pass arguments to wceload.  You'll have to do it via RAPI.

Comment: Just as a note - VS uses a CoreCon client to do this, not RAPI.  You could follow a similar pattern and have your desktop app act as a remote tool.